# ng-repeat used to display data, when data is updated via the save button, how do I update the ng-repeat without updating the entire page?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs

This is the div that contains the HTML with the list:

```
 <div id="searchResults" class="container-fluid">

                <table ng-show="HasMyData()" class="table table-striped table-condensed table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="text-center smalltext bold">Version</th>
                            <th class="text-center smalltext bold">City</th>
                            <th class="smalltext bold">Description</th>
                            <th class="text-center smalltext bold">Food</th>
                            <th class="text-center smalltext bold">Lizard</th>
                            <th class="text-center smalltext bold">Lost</th>

                            <th class="text-center smalltext bold">Complete</th>
                            <th class="text-center smalltext bold">Active</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr style="cursor:pointer;" ng-class="{ selectedrow: isSelectedReg($id) }" ng-click="GetDetails(data,$id)" ng-show="numberOfRecords != 0"
                            ng-repeat="data in myData | 
                            filter:{'name':FilterByDescription(search.val)} |
                            filter:{'isFood':FilterIsFood} |
                            filter:{'isLizard':FilterIsLizard} |
                            filter:{'isLost':FilterIsLost} |
                            filter:{'reviewCompleted':FilterByComplete()} | 
                            filter:{'activeInd':FilterByInactive() }">
                            <td class="text-center smalltext">{{data.versionNumber}}</td>
                            <td class="text-center smalltext">{{data.cityName}}</td>
                            <td class="smalltext">{{data.name}}</td>
                            <td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" ng-checked="data.isFood" disabled></td>
                            <td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" ng-checked="data.isLizard" disabled></td>
                            <td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" ng-checked="data.isLost" disabled></td>
                            <td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" ng-checked="data.reviewCompleted" disabled></td>
                            <td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" ng-checked="data.activeInd" disabled></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr ng-show="numberOfRecords == 0">
                            <td colspan="5">NO RECORDS FOUND</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
```

The data is updated via a form, and then the above div/ng-repeat should be reloaded after the update.  I've read a few posts that say it should be automatic...but it's not happening.

Comment: Can you provide us with the logic for the save button where the data is updated?  If the DOM isn't updating automatically throw a `$timeout` around the line where `myData` is updated.  That does a `$scope.$apply()` in a safe way.

Comment: if you save data to `myData` in database, do you fetch the latest record after saving and update `myData`?